# Pycharm 3.4.1 - "AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet". Django Rest framewrok

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm using `DRF` and `Pycharm 3.4.1` and `Django 1.7`. When I try to test my serializer class via Pycharm django console, it gives me the following error:

**Code**

```
from items_app.serializers import ItemSerializer
s = ItemSerializer()
print(repr(s))
```

then cause the following error traceback:

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 440, in __repr__
    return unicode_to_repr(representation.serializer_repr(self, indent=1))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/utils/representation.py", line 75, in serializer_repr
    fields = serializer.fields
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 312, in fields
    for key, value in self.get_fields().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 883, in get_fields
    info = model_meta.get_field_info(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/utils/model_meta.py", line 68, in get_field_info
    reverse_relations = _get_reverse_relationships(opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/utils/model_meta.py", line 129, in _get_reverse_relationships
    for relation in opts.get_all_related_objects():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 498, in get_all_related_objects
    include_proxy_eq=include_proxy_eq)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 510, in get_all_related_objects_with_model
    self._fill_related_objects_cache()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 533, in _fill_related_objects_cache
    for klass in self.apps.get_models(include_auto_created=True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 101, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 168, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

but when I'm using my terminal(instead of pycharm django console), It works properly! I know there is a problem with `Pycharm` but I don't know how to fix it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Loading the app registry is part of the `django.setup` method. If the app registry is not loaded when you start using the console, the most likely reason is that it is a plain python console instead of a fully blown Django console.

Try the following code. If that solves it, you are indeed using a plain python console.

```
>>> import django
>>> django.setup()
```